# Cannot fit unknown into the function parameter string list item

Tags: expression, azure-data-factory

I am trying to remove dbo from tablename using expression.

```
TableName: dbo.product

@concat('schema.',split(item().tablename,'.')[1])
```

I need to replace dbo to schema from tablename. would anyone please help. I tried the above code but it is giving an error: Cannot fit unknown into the function parameter string list item.

Comment: I got the same error in the dynamic content editor, but somehow debug option works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try debugging it? I also got a similar error in expression builder, but when I run my pipeline, it is still able to get the output as 'schema.product'.